# How do I access the integer in this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, html

I want to extract the integers from "Jonas" and then do calculations and conditional stuff. how do I go about doing this?

```
$kontroliniai = array("Jonas" => array("Matematika"=>9,
                                       "Lietuviu"=> 5,
                                       "Anglu"=>7)
```

Comment: `$kontroliniai['Jonas']['Mathematika']` etc - You aren't very clear on what you are actually trying to do, but this is how you access keys in a multidimensional array.

Comment: What I'm trying to do ,is access the ints associated with "Matematika","Lietuviu" etc. and then do calculations with them if possible

Comment: What kind of calculations? You are being very vague, but the code depends 100% on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically these are grades for an imaginary student, and I want to find the average of his grades ,and then take that grade average and put it in if statement something like if($average<8) echo"text"

Comment: Jonas is the student and `Matematika` and stuff are grades? This was pretty unclear since you didn't post code in english

Comment: Yea I thought it'd be self-explanatory ,but it makes sense its more complicated cause of the language barrier,but yea you got the gist of it

Comment: @Auridas I noticed you have a lot of questions that have answers that do not have an accepted answer. If an answer helps you on StackOverflow, you should check the checkmark to the left of the answer to give yourself and the person who helped you some extra rep for their time. If you do not do this, people may start to get discouraged from answering your questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

> Basically these are grades for an imaginary student, and I want to find the average of his grades ,and then take that grade average and put it in if statement something like if($average<8)
>
> (Comment From OP)

Okay, try this:

```
$kontroliniai = array(
    "Jonas" => array(
        "Matematika"=>9,
        "Lietuviu"=> 5,
        "Anglu"=>7
    ),
    "GrumpyCrouton" => array(
        "Matematika"=>10,
        "Lietuviu"=> 8,
        "Anglu"=>9
    ),
);

foreach($kontroliniai as $key => $grades) {

    //calculate average by summing all grades and dividing by amount of grades.
    $average = array_sum($grades) / count($grades);
    
    //echo results
    if($average < 8) {
        echo "$key average less than 8 (Average: $average)";
    } else {
        echo "$key average more than 8 (Average: $average)";
    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```

This will work even if you add more students into the array. In this case, it will output

```
Jonas average less than 8 (Average: 7)<br>
GrumpyCrouton average more than 8 (Average: 9)<br>
```

---

### References

[`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) - Calculate the sum of values in an array.

[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) - Count all elements in an array, or something in an object.

[`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) - provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.

Comment: Yup this was what I wanted I wasn't aware there was something like array_sum,thanks for the help ,cheers!